# Question on the Power efficiency of a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I wanted to find the effect of load resistance on the power efficiency of a circuit. When I apply the max power transfer theorem, the internal resistance of a cell = the load resistance right? So when the load resistance is not equal to the internal resistance of the cell, how do I find the internal resistance of the cell at that load resistance?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: Efficiency has usually very little to do with maximum power transfer.

Comment: Apparently, the power efficiency increases as the load resistance increases. So,Im trying to get that graph.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem#Maximizing_power_transfer_versus_power_efficiency

Comment: What they said. Note that "efficiency" is a strange term when used as it is here. As i flows in source and load then efficiency increases as more power is dissipated in load and less in source. So as Rl >> Rsource efficincy is high and when Rl approaches  infinitely high efficiency approaches 100%. ie transferring zero power maximises efficiency. Not very useful. Siilarly max current occurs when Rl=0. You get zero power transfer and zero volts n load and zero efficiency but max current :-). Also usually not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***The maximum power transfer condition results in an efficiency of only 50%***

Explanation:

Suppose the source voltage below, where \$V\$ and \$R_i\$ are the internal voltage and internal resistance.

[image: R divider - battery]

The Load Power is:

$$ P_L = \left (\frac{V}{R_i+R_L} \right )^2 R_L$$

In order to maximize \$P_L\$, we do \$\frac{dP}{dR_L}=0\$; and this occurs when \$R_L=R_i\$. In other words, in this condition, the maximum power is delivered to the load \$R_L\$

Now, the input power \$P\$ is given by:

$$ P = \frac{V^2}{R_i+R_L} $$

The efficiency in percentage is:

$$ E = \frac{P_L}{P}\times 100 $$

or

$$ E = \frac{R_L}{R_i+R_L}\times 100 $$

When \$R_L=R_i\$:

$$ E = 50 \% $$

This low efficiency in the condition of maximum power transfer for battery operated devices is not recommended. From the plot below you can see that a condition of 75% efficiency is a good compromise between power and battery life.

[image: Load Power x efficiency]

Comment: We know the max power is when Rl=Ri right? And in the graph the max  power is when RL=5 ohms that means that Ri=5 ohms. So my question is how do I calculate the efficiency of the circuit when the RL=2.5 ohms or when the RL=10 ohms? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Simply use my  fourth equation (\$E = \frac{R_L}{R_i+R_L}\times 100\$), replacing the actual values you mentioned. The plot above is for \$R_i = 5 \$ Ohm.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a source \$V_s\$ with an internal resistance \$R_s\$ connected to a load of \$R_L\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3sdsA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Current in the circuit \$I_L\$
$$I_L={V_s \over R_s+R_L} \tag 1$$
Power of the load \$P_L\$
$$P_L=|I_L|^2R_L ={V_s^2 R_L \over (R_s+R_L)^2}$$
and the efficieny \$ \eta\$
$$\eta={R_L \over R_s+R_L}$$
now, if you want to maximize \$P_L\$ evaluate 
$${dP_L \over d R_L}=0 \Rightarrow R_L=R_s$$
and the maximum power
$$P_{L-max}={V_s^2 \over 4 R_L}$$
However, when you have maximum power transfer, efficiency will only be limited to 50%.
See the following graph for a numerical example: \$ V_s= 10~V, R_s=50 \Omega~\$
[image]

**Keep in mind that in practical applications, $\R_s\$ may not be a constant - It can vary with the load variation**

> do I find the internal resistance of the cell at that load resistance?

If you know the current or the voltage across the load, you can simply use equation (1) above to estimate the effective source resistance

Comment: We know the max power is when Rl=Ri right? And in the graph the max power is when RL=5 ohms that means that Ri=5 ohms. So my question is how do I calculate the efficiency of the circuit when the RL=2.5 ohms or when the RL=10 ohms? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: As @DirceuRodriguesJr mentioned, you can the equation for efficiency by assuming source resistance does not change.